# Why is my command not found but works in the command line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

This is a part of my script:

```
read -p "[q] What is the meteor project's location? "
PATH=$REPLY
cd $PATH
cd src
echo $(pwd)
mrt bundle bundle.tar.gz
```

It prints the correct working directory. Entering `mrt bundle bundle.tar.gz` in the console works.
Executing my script, I get `meteor_bundle.sh: line 9: bash: command not found`. What could be the reason?

Comment: It only looks on the `PATH`. You need to echo the `$PATH` _in both cases_. The difference will probably explain this problem.

Comment: Ah, oh, I see. I overwrite the `$PATH` variable and that's why `mrt`, which resides somewhere in `/bin`, is not available anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You choose the variable name poorly: `PATH`has a special meaning in Bash: it is used to indicate Bash where to look for executable programs. Choose another name (preferably lowercase, see @Gordon's comment) and it should be fine.

Comment: Yes, that was a poor choice. Thank you for helping me out; I did not see it, although it nearly was the only variable in that script :-)

Comment: This is why it's a good idea to use lowercase (or mixed-case) variable names in shell scripts -- there are a bunch of special-meaning variables, and it's easy to overwrite one by mistake... but all the special ones are uppercase.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the full path for `mrt` because you changed the value of the `PATH`. Or choose another name for the variable from the second line.

See the following post to understand exactly what is the purpose of the `PATH` *environment* variable:

- http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html